# how to show logs running on remote server in jenkins job in real time

Tags: shell, jenkins, logging, scripting, aix

I have a shell script named `startNode.sh` on a remote AIX server named `remoteserver1`.
I am triggering the `startNode.sh` script on remote server with the help of a Jenkins pipeline job. I am using grovy command `sh` to just run the script over ssh.

```
sh "ssh user@remoteserver1 startNode.sh"
```

In console output of the job I could not see the output of the script as the job is seems to skip it. I redirected the output to a log file and want to show the logs in real time.

```
sh "ssh user@remoteserver1 'startNode.sh > output.log' "
```

How can we do it? is there some plugin or something with which we can show the logs.

I tried tail -f but it did not work. I am using cat in 5 minutes interval till 25 minutes as my script takes max 20 minute to complete. how can I show the logs in the real time to the Jenkins console output?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What happens if you run this command without any jenkins or pipeline: `ssh user@remoteserver1 startNode.sh`

Answer (score 0):

I would enter the `cat` command on the error file after running the `startNode.sh` script step in your Jenkins job. After the `startNode.sh` file has finished running, the whole error file will be outputted into the Jenkins job console output.

Comment: I am already doing it but I want real time logs like we get on tailf